# Creating a two way lookup Price Matrix in Excel using VBA (Index/Match/SumProduct)

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match, sumproduct

I'm trying to create a pricing matrix for products but using Index/Match or SumProduct formulas are proving to be a nightmare for me, I'm wondering if VBA would be easier?

Essentially if a product width or height is in between two figures, I need the price quoted to take on the next pricing bracket.  (NB: Rounding up or using Ceiling functions within the formula doesn't work for me either)

Examples of the code I've tried using are:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(HeightRange=CEILING(Height,1000))*--(WidthRange=CEILING(Width,10))*PriceRange)`

`=INDEX(PriceRange,MATCH(MIN(ABS(HeightRange-Height)),ABS(HeightRange-Height),-1),MATCH(MIN(ABS(WidthRange-Width)),ABS(WidthRange-Width),-1))`

Example Table:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of `=AGGREGATE()` like so:

`=INDEX(A:E,AGGREGATE(15,3,(($A$4:$A$11>=N3)/($A$4:$A$11>=N3))*ROW($A$4:$A$11),1),AGGREGATE(15,3,(($B$3:$J$3>=M3)/($B$3:$J$3>=M3))*COLUMN($B$3:$J$3),1))`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=INDEX(B:J,MATCH(N3,A:A),MATCH(M3,B$3:J$3))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however this doesn't work for me as if I select width 1601 and height 1750 I want it to return a value of £111, not £96 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly formulas just like both guys said above...
Mine here:

```
=INDEX($A:$J,MATCH($N3,$A:$A,0),MATCH($M3,B$3:J$3,0))
```